# Retrieve file path downloaded via wget

Tags: wget

I am downloading files with `wget` command

```
wget abc.com -nH -r -l1 --no-parent
```

This is storing files in different sub folders. I want path of each download file. So, how do I get it ?

Example:
wget is downloading file to:

```
c:/test/com/test/pacakage/filename1.text
c:/test/com1/test/package1/filename2.text
```

So, how to retrieve complete file path - ie. `com/test/package/filename1.text` ?

Thanks